# How to access Child Table Records on the basis of Parent in Flask

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am developing a Flask app which connects with my `phpMyAdmin` database using `Flask-SQLAlchemy`. Now in that database I have 2 tables `Posts` and `Paragraphs` such that there are multiple paragraphs associated with one post i.e Paragraphs table has a foreign key `PostSNo` which is the Primary Key with name `SNo` in Posts table. The Posts table has a `slug` column. So what I am trying to achieve is I want to fetch all those Paragraphs records whose
`Postsno (Foreign Key Column in Paragraphs) == SNo (Primary Key of Posts table)`

Here's what I tried but it is raising an exception:

```py
class Posts(db.Model):
    '''
    Integrating with and Fetching Data from Posts Table
    '''
    sno = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=True)
    slug = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)


class Paragraphs(db.Model):
    '''
    Integrating with and Fetching Data from Paragraphs Table
    '''
    sno = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    paraindex = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    content = db.Column(db.String(10000), nullable=False)
    imageurl = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
    postsno = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)


# App Route to Post Page
@app.route('/post/<string:post_slug>', methods=['GET'])
def post(post_slug):
    post = Posts.query.filter_by(slug=post_slug)
    para = Paragraphs.query.filter_by(postsno=post.sno)
    return render_template('post.html', post=[post, para])
```

The Exception it is raising is
`AttributeError: 'BaseQuery' object has no attribute 'sno'`

Answer (score -1):

I think you want this:

```
post = Posts.query.filter_by(slug=post_slug).all()
para = Paragraphs.query.filter_by(postsno=post.sno).all()
```

Other operators such as first() or first() are also available but I assume you want all matching records.

Comment: What I want to do is I want to fetch the associated child records on the basis of parent's primary key

Comment: What I posted should at least fix the AttributeError you have. Did you try it ?

Comment: yes I tried it and it does help me in not raising attribute error but on the same time it doesn't solve the problem either. But still, Thanks for answering, maybe it could help me in future in my other doubts.